# How to manipulate OSX Lion desktop spaces in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, desktop, space

I'm specifically hoping to find out if there is a way to create a new Mission Control desktop space using the Terminal, or even using Automator.

My apologies if this is a trivial question.  I'm fairly new to using the Terminal and I've been googling things having to do with Terminal manipulation of desktop spaces/Mission Control to no avail.

Comment: Have a look at [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606221/how-can-i-programmatically-add-a-space-to-mission-control)