# List all available Mission Control spaces programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

Is there a way to get a list of all the available Mission Control spaces in macOS with Cocoa or Carbon (Objective-C)?

Comment: Thank you @matt but I think that applies to processes and not workspaces, unless I missed something.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `NSWorkSpace` of another app? Or do you want to get the Spaces of Mission Control?

Comment: @Willeke I want to get the spaces of Mission Control, which I think are NSWorkSpace's instances

Comment: @matt I'm thinking on Mission Control spaces

Comment: Interesting discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243364/341994 Try searching on "mission control" for more.

Comment: Thank you @matt, that is helpful, I had the idea that Mission Control spaces were actually NSWorkspace instances (or at least were related), but I think I was wrong.